# How to display city limits using google maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If I do a search for a city or neighbourhood which google recognizes, like [Fernwood, Victoria](http://maps.google.ca/maps?q=fernwood%20victoria&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x548f746349c1243b:0xb97bf6f39d5e69fc,Fernwood,%20Victoria,%20BC&gl=ca&ei=hziKT8WoD8nJiQLYo5TlCw&sa=X&oi=geocode_result&ct=title&resnum=2&ved=0CDEQ8gEwAQ), I get a pretty map with a drawn boundary. Is there any way to access this kind of information with the google maps API?

I am not looking to draw my own lines on maps, I am looking to make a map showing multiple neighbourhoods with limits on the same map. Bonus points for the ability to style these limits (eg: fill them in like a regular polygon)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this kind of functionality is not supported by the api and works only for google maps.
I had implement this by finding the boundaries that i needed insert them in my postgis db and then send them with json whenever the polygon was within the map viewport.

Hope it helps